# How to xlf-translate soy template by plovr?

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-templates, plovr

```
{msg desc="Says hello and tells user to click a link."}
  Hello {$userName}! Please click <a href="{$url}">here</a>.
{/msg}
```

what set config file or request params in plovr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this fork of plovr which has support for soy translations via XLF (doesn't come with default plovr).  You'll need Java 7 to build/run it.

https://github.com/rgpower/plovr/tree/soy-translation

See the most recent commit for plovr cfg syntax related to XLF translations.